# std::cout for map<string, int>

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, cout

I have a map declared as follows

```
map<string, int> symbolTable;


if(tempLine.substr(0,1) == "("){
            symbolTable.insert(pair<string, int>(tempLine, lineCount));
        }
```

How do I ***std::cout*** all of the things in my symbol table?

Comment: Another way of doing the insert would be `symbolTable[tempLine] = lineCount;` , or `symbolTable.insert({tempLine, lineCount});`

Comment: _"How do I std::cout all of the things"_ I want that on a T-shirt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In modern C++:

```
for (auto&& item : symbolTable)
    cout << item.first << ": " << item.second << '\n';
```

If you only have access to a pre-C++11 compiler the code would be:

```
for ( map<string, int>::const_iterator it = symbolTable.begin(); it != symbolTable.end(); ++it)
    cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting a whole bunch of "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&&’ token" errors, am I missing a library?

Comment: @BarneyChambers what compiler and version?

Comment: Using g++ I am using version 4.4.7

Comment: @chris: (that was before he added '\n')

Comment: I don't think auto&& is a good idea. first, you miss `const`. which seems not   too harmful here. The problem is few people know about `reference collapsing`, I feel it's better to be explicit.

Comment: @BarneyChambers try using flag `-std=c++11` , I think g++ 4.4 should be capable

Comment: @XiaotianPei `auto&&` always works so I default to using it unless I have brainpower to spare :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative if your compiler isn't C++11 compliant:

```
for (map<string, int>::iterator it = symbolTable.begin();
    it != symbolTable.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
}
```

And for completeness, if it is:

```
for (auto& s : symbolTable)
{
    cout << s.first << " " << s.second << endl;
}
```

Comment: it's better to add `const`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to print all the key/value pairs. The code following is an example in C++11

```
for (const auto& kv : symbolTable) {
    std::cout << kv.first << " " << kv.second << '\n';
}
```

ps: Both of other two answers pay little attention to `const`, which is quite sad...

Comment: It's better to use `'\n'` rather than `"\n"`.  Unnecessary braces make me sad too, but each to their own ;-.